# Homologous but not homotopic paths

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

How can I see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/abec/30dae6b212a26d26739f93b4bea66e1dc20c.pdf) on page 2 in figure 1(b) that
$\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are homologous?

Comment: You have the definition of being homologous on page 3, the section 2.1. Read it and look at the picture again

Comment: There the author uses some equivalent definition of "being homologous" for curves starting at the same point, but I would like to see that $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are homologous via the basic definition.

Answer (score 1):

One way to visualize it is to note that your space is homotopically equivalent to a figure eight "$\infty$", and that your path $\tau_1 *\tau_2$ ($*$ being concatenation, represented left to right) is homotopically equivalent to the path $a*b*a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ (where $a,b$ represent the "left" and "right" paths on the figure eight, with orientation given by "positive=starting down").

Homologically, we have that $[a*b*a^{-1}*b^{-1}]=0$ (by Hurewicz, say), whereas since $\pi_1(\infty)$ is the free group generated by $a,b$, we have that $a*b*a^{-1}*b^{-1}$ is non-zero.

Comment: How do I understand what the author says: Two trajectories $q_1$and $q_2$ connecting the same start and
end points are homologous if and only if the closed loop formed by them
$q_1 \bigsqcup -q_2$ forms the boundary of 2-dimensional region on the plane not containing/intersecting any obstacles.
 I.e. of which 2-dimensional region are $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ boundary of?The regoin at which  $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ intersect is not 2-dimensional there! It has singularity at the intersection.